# Should tags without description be allowed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I just earned the create new tag privilege and this made me curious to check out the current NEW tags created. For my surprise I noticed that there are quite a few tags without description.

I know that a good tag name should "speak for it self" but how hard could it be to make a tag description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags exist without descriptions, because the tag needs someone with the knowledge to fill in that data! The user asking/creating the tag might not always know the best way to describe the tag software.

If you're lower than a certain reputation, every tag wiki edit you submit gets you two reputation points, so you can take the initiative to help document all the tags!

Comment: ok, understood! That is another great way to get users involved. I am new to this platform and keep getting amazed with how well and carefully thought it is! :-)